# There is no overloaded version of 'toString' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: delphi

I am running a simple program that convert JSON into a Delphi class. I am a beginner, so there might be multiple things wrong with it.

This is the function I am using:

```
with TStringBuilder.Create do
  try
    for s in List do
      Append(s);

    Result := ToString(True);
  finally
    free;
  end;
```

The error I am getting is:

> There is no overloaded version of 'toString' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? The overload of `TStringBuilder.ToString()` that takes a `Boolean` parameter was introduced in 10.3 Rio. In any case, there is no need to update the builder's Capacity since you are destroying the builder immediately after retrieving the string, so just omit the Boolean. Then the code will compile.